# Wrap text in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I have this algorithm that contains a very long line and I need to wrap this line because it is not appear completely when I build a PDF file.
Many thanks

```
\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlCapFnt{\scriptsize}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\footnotesize}
\footnotesize
\caption{Caption}
\label{algorithm-1}
$Here..... I have very long line that I need to be wrapped $\;
 \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Does the line contain a large math formula? Can you provide a more concrete example showing the equation so we can have an idea of what exactly you mean?

Comment: Many thanks. No it dose not contain any formula. It is just a readable text.

Comment: Then there is no need for using the `$`...`$` as readible text should not be in math mode. Moreover, readable text will naturally break at the end of the line anyway. If this is not the case, then you need to supply more information.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the $

Algorithm wrap lines but formula are never wrapped, even in a standard paragraph.